# Java Servlet: structuring a legacy webapp. What framework or technology?

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml, project-structuring

I'm developing a Web app (unfortunately a legacy one) in java (that runs on tomcat) with a very small, but not well organized (at least on this particular project), group and let me start by saying we have not much of experience in servlets programming.

The issue is the folloing.

I'm having kind of a trouble as the amount of servlets keep growing and growing while we implement new functions in this webapp. We don't have a project to follow and structure. Just the clint who randomly asks for new functionality out of the blue.

I would just say our web.xml is a mess. I think we should avoid to pollute the web.xml so much with new servlet every time (right now is about 800 lines and it's becoming hard to maintain), but i'm not sure about what i should do about it.

I'm exploring different possibilities, but we can't afford to explore too much so i would like to hear some idea or best practies from people with more experience than us.

I was thinking that maybe we should use CORBA ore something like that to implenet some kind of RPC. So while grouping common functionalities in a few bunch of servlets we could tame the chaos. Could it be a good idea?

What i have in mind is something like a few servlets that pose as entry points for the requests. I would like to group them by the type of response they give. So for example i have a servlet that serves me json after calling some other class that actually do the job to extract data ore manipulating data. Or again i would have a servlet that serves me files, files that another class or servlet produce. And so on. Am i looking at the problem in the right way?

I took a looked at some framework like DWR (Direct Web Remoting) but we would need to integrate it with a legacy webapp with ugly jsp pages full of scriptlet and we can't afford to jump into full ajax web pages in the limited time we have for the project.
We would need something more lightweight.

The more i search for a solution the more i get confused and overwelmed by the possibilities i find (REST, ORB, RPC, JSON-RPC...), so i ask for your help. Thanks in advance for every answers and tips.

Comment: _"I was thinking that maybe we should use CORBA ore something like that to implenet some kind of RPC"_

Are you serious? CORBA is to be found only in museums since long time

Comment: The two answers below are good. Spring is a framework specifically designed to fix the problem you have. But underneath it all, what spring MVC does is implement something called the 'Front Controller Pattern'.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern
This pattern is actually quite difficult to implement in a traditional simple Servlet application because of limitations with the format of web.xml, but it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely look into the **Spring framework** which is the de-facto standard for Java web development nowadays: http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/

The **Play Framework** is also an interesting framework, giving you a Ruby-like development cycle: https://www.playframework.com/

Comment: More specifically spring boot - it gives you a starting point set of defaults

Answer (score 0):

Hello many of your points are valid so you can use new frameworks like `spring` or `struts` but it needs huge change over as many new levels will get added/introduced.But if you want to just get ride of many servlets you can/should use `MVC` architecture like `framework` in addition to that use a central level `controller(a main servlet)`-this will just take the `request` and checks in it (like `switch case`) as soon as `switch case` matched that `helper class / utility class` should called via `instance` or `statically` after that the `response` should also from that `helper/utility` class and should be sent to the main `controller` and that main `controller` will send it to respective `jsps/html`.